# libQt5Core.so.5 malformed in docker fedora:29

Tags: linux, qt, docker

I am currently using Fedora 29 in a Docker to generate some RPMs. The host is under Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS) and the docker use the `--privileged` flag to start.

Since 2/3 weeks the pipeline is broken, `/usr/lib64/qt5/bin/lrelease` and other binaries from `qt5-linguist` are not able to find `libQt5Core.so.5` even if the shared object is here. But the weirdest is coming:

```sh
[root@28ffba3f3995 /]# ldd /usr/lib64/qt5/bin/lrelease-qt5
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce5b5d000)
    libQt5Xml.so.5 => /lib64/libQt5Xml.so.5 (0x00007fbb0ac01000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbb0abe0000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbb0aa48000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbb0a8c4000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbb0a8a9000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbb0a6e1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbb0acc9000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
[root@28ffba3f3995 /]# ls -la /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Dec 21 20:08 /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5 -> libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
[root@28ffba3f3995 /]# ls -la /lib64/libQt5Xml.so.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Dec 21 20:08 /lib64/libQt5Xml.so.5 -> libQt5Xml.so.5.11.3
[root@28ffba3f3995 /]# file /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: symbolic link to libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
[root@28ffba3f3995 /]# file /lib64/libQt5Xml.so.5
/lib64/libQt5Xml.so.5: symbolic link to libQt5Xml.so.5.11.3
[root@28ffba3f3995 /]# LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECT=1 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
This is the QtCore library version Qt 5.11.3 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 8.2.1 20181215 (Red Hat 8.2.1-6))
Copyright (C) 2016 The Qt Company Ltd.
Contact: http://www.qt.io/licensing/

Installation prefix: /usr
Library path:        lib64
Include path:        include/qt5
Processor features:  sse3 sse2[required] ssse3 fma cmpxchg16b sse4.1 sse4.2 movbe popcnt aes avx f16c rdrand bmi hle avx2 bmi2 rtm rdseed
```

And again:

```sh
# In strace lrelease I see:
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

The file is read!

`ldconfig` does nothing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
strip -R .note.ABI-tag /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
```

Comment: Yes, it should work (as specified here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3023#issue-305053328).

I don't have the time to test, but I think I will fix my pipeline when I will add Fedora 30 too.